# Make Horizontal Indeterminate ProgressBar a Fixed Width

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I currently have a horizontal `ProgressBar` defined in `XML` as below, that I am using to show the progress of an item loading:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading_progressbar"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:indeterminateBehavior="repeat"
    android:indeterminateDuration="1000"
 android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/custom_loading_progressbar" />
```

Here is the custom drawable to allow me to colour the `ProgessBar` how I wish:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/black" />
            <size android:height="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/black" />
                <size android:height="2dp" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/white" />
                <size android:height="2dp" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The issue I have with the current indeterminate implementation is that it pulses between being a small width and a larger width. This can be seen in the second `ProgressBar` at this link:

https://materialdoc.com/images/linear-progress-1.gif

I purely want to be able to specify a width of 100dp and allow it to keep cycling through its repeats until complete.

Is there any way to set a fixed width for an indeterminate `ProgressBar`?